# Executing resolvers one after the other in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Given the following route:

```
path: '',
component: MyComponent,
resolve: {
    foo: FooResolver,
    bar: BarResolver
}
```

Is there any way of telling angular to execute the first resolver `FooResolver`, and only execute the second resolver `BarResolver` once the first one has finished?

Comment: It depends on what `foo` and `bar` are and why they should be resolved in this order. But generally this is achievable with FooBarResolver that resolves to an object that contains foo and bar.

Comment: @estus I was thinking about doing that, and if there's no other way I will, but I'd prefer to do it with different resolvers for reutilization purposes.

Comment: @estus basically `foo` and `bar` are json objects retrieved from a database, I don't care of the order of execution, but they must be executed one after the other.

Comment: I had same problem but more complex. In my case `bar` and `baz` depended on `foo` but `baz` was optional in some routes. Eventually I ended up with `FooBarBaz` resolver that took care of optional Baz. To my knowledge, there is currently no better way.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Resolvers are resolved in parallel. If `Foo` and `Bar` are supposed to be resolved in series they should be a single `FooBar` resolver. If they are supposed to be used by themselves in other routes, `FooBar` can wrap `Foo` and `Bar` resolvers:

```
class FooBarResolver implements Resolve<{ foo: any, bar: any }> {
  constructor(
    protected fooResolver: FooResolver,
    protected barResolver: BarResolver
  ) {}

  async resolve(route): Promise<{ foo: any, bar: any }> {
    const foo = await this.fooResolver.resolve(route);
    const bar = await this.barResolver.resolve(route);

    return { foo, bar };
  }
}
```

`FooBar` should be aware of the fact if it is a promise or an observable that is returned from `Foo` and `Bar` in order to resolve them properly. Otherwise additional safety device should be added, like `await Observable.from(this.fooResolver.resolve(route)).toPromise()`.

`FooBar` and `Foo` or `Bar` shouldn't appear within same route because this will result in duplicate resolutions.

Comment: @DanyGauthier As with any other resolver, it's specified as `resolve: { fooBar: FooBarResolver }` on the route and resolved data is available as `activatedRoute.data['fooBar'].foo`, etc in route component.

Answer (score 1):

I found a slightly more elegant solution that can be used if you don't care about the results from all of the resolvers:

```
class FooBarResolver implements Resolve<Observable<any>> {
    constructor(
        protected fooResolver: FooResolver,
        protected barResolver: BarResolver
    ) { }

    resolve(): Observable<any>
    {
        return this.fooResolver.resolve().pipe(
            concat(this.barResolver.resolve()),
            concat(this.barResolver.resolve())
        );
    }
}
```

I use this to trigger the data loading in my services. And because they write the data / isLoading / error into an Akita storage, I don't care about the results of the resolvers.

Answer (score 1):

One other option is to wrap your dependent routes and use necessary resolver on wrapper.

I.E.

```
{ path: '', resolve: { foo$: FooResolver }, children: [
    { path: 'mySubRoute', resolve:  {bar$: BarResolver }, component: BarComponent }
]}
```

*If you meet with relative path resolving problems, try using

```
relativeLinkResolution: "corrected"
```

In forRoot router method. More info here [Angular RouterLink relative path does not work in component having empty path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61259145/angular-routerlink-relative-path-does-not-work-in-component-having-empty-path)

Answer (score 0):

I tackled this scenario using `combineLatest` in a single `resolver`. You can do this:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class FooBarResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(
    private readonly fooResolver: FooResolver,
    private readonly barResolver: BarResolver  
  ) {}

  resolve() {
    return combineLatest(
      this.fooResolver.resolve(), 
      this.barResolver.resolve()
    ).pipe(map(([users, posts]) => ({users, posts})))
  }
}
```