# Angular RouterLink relative path does not work in component having empty path

Tags: angular, url, router, routerlink

I have my child path defined as

`{ path: '', component: CartMainComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }`

The whole path looks like this when I am in CartMainComponent
`http://mystype.com/brand/MyBrandId/cart`
In the cart I want to navigate to `/brand/MyBrandId/cart` so I used `routerLink="../cart"` in html. But this gave me next error

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'brand/Rotiform/cart/catalog'

Only when I do `routerLink="../../../cart"` it works

This is illogical, even if the empty path is treated as an additional level of relative path. Still I expect to use '..' only twice but not three times

Is it possible to fix it so I can relatively go through route without thinking if there are any empty paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Angular team added a fix for this issue, but you need to enable it manually by adding

`relativeLinkResolution: 'corrected'` in root router configuration. I.e.

`@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'corrected'})],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})`

But please, note that this 'bugfix' didn't solve the whole bug. This is why it is not enabled by default.
This PR describes the problem: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26983
Please keep it in mind.

RelativeLinkResolution is also discussed in this github thread
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13011

Comment: But, For my project that I migrated from Angular 11.2.2 to 15.2.8.     Throws this error at compile time [Argument of type '{ useHash: true; relativeLinkResolution: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ExtraOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'relativeLinkResolution' does not exist in type 'ExtraOptions'.

44     relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy'].    [it was working fine till last version] the path should resolve like this => [localhost:4200/#/dashboard]

Comment: @Vishesh corrected is now a default behavior for angular 15. You app must work fine with it. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37355#issuecomment-736521495

Comment: Yes it works find , after the relativeLinkResolution is removed . Like this ----> imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)].      ------------- In Angular15, relativeLinkResolution is not one of the property of ExtraOptions interface which is the second argument in forRoot(Routes[] , ExtraOptions)